# Matlab print function is producing a document not a jpeg

Tags: printing, jpeg, matlab-figure

I am using Matlab to produce publishable graphs and have encountered problems with the print function for the first time despite having used it identically before. I can't figure out why it has stopped working.

When I run my script with

```
print(1,'-djpeg','My_Figure','-r300')
```

at the end, the results is a file that is a document type, not a jpeg.

Has anyone encountered this before or have any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: the first argument is the handle to the figure. Are you sure that this is always == 1 ?

Comment: The figure I am trying to print is figure (1), though I am using subplot. However it has worked for me before. The only thing I can think of is the fact that I am now using a Mac; prior I was using Windows.

Comment: Still I would suggest to make sure, that you are using the correct object (handle). Next thing: try just to use the parameters absolutely needed. Perhaps you need to add the file-extension-> My_Figure.jpeg?

Comment: Adding .jpeg worked! Thank you so much, you have saved me from a massive headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed within the comments->

One can try to append the file-extension:

```
print(1,'-djpeg','My_Figure.jpeg','-r300')
```

As this is documented different:

> If filename does not include an extension, print appends an appropriate extension.

[TMW: print](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html)

..it seems to depend on either the Matlab-Version or the OS Matlab is running on.